# How to upload font awesome icon on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, font-awesome, amazon-cloudfront

I am using cloudfront to serve fonts and images.
For that I Have created the s3 bucket and give the origin in the cloudfront.
But I dont know how to upload font-awesome in the s3 bucket.
I uploaded the css file and gave the link in my html page but everytime I got error in console like failed to load icon

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main reason to use Cloudfront + S3 is to serve a secured (ssl) static content site, is that your case?

Comment: yes, i am using to serve the font-awesome and google icons

Answer (score 0):

Just uploading the css files won't work.

You need to upload webfonts/svgs etc folders maintaining the relative path.

Also after upload. Make them publicly accessible (by default it won't be on s3)

Download the whole package from https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Comment: But it is not possible to upload the folder on s3 is there any way to do that .

Comment: Another way is to modify the fontawesome css. Open the css file you want to upload. You'll see it's trying to import some external files (e.g: src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot"); ) ... find that font file and upload separately. After that edit the css file to put the absolute path of that font file (eot and other extension) (e.g: src: url("https://absolute_path_here/fa-brands-400.eot")  )

Answer (score 0):

You should add a CORS configuration to your bucket's properties to allow certain http methods.

Edit the following code and insert it in S3 like so:

> 1. Select the bucket in question.
> 2. Select the "Properties" tab.
> 3. Expand the "Permissions" section.
> 4. Click the button "Edit CORS Configuration" and insert your edited configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.your-site.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.your-site.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Now it should work properly.

Comment: I have already added cors but i only uploaded the css file i think thats the issue

Comment: Try @Afzal's answer then.